VBA script to read an excel, write the values into a word file, then format values as Heading1, Heading2 etc
I am writing a macro that will read an excel table and write the values in the table into an excel file. I would like the macro to take the values from column A and format them to Heading1 style, and the values from column B and format them to Heading2 style, and finally the values from column C should be just Normal style.
Sub magicmacro()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:D10")

'word file part
Dim DocApp As Object
Dim DocFile As Object
Dim DocName As String

On Error Resume Next

Set DocApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Err.Clear
    Set DocApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

DocApp.Visible = True
'DocName = "C:\Users\ggujadhur\Downloads\output.docx"
DocName = "C:\Users\nicolas.jouffroy\Downloads\output.docx"

If Dir(DocName) = "" Then
    'MsgBox "File " & DocName & vbCrLf & "not found " & vbCrLf & "C:\Users\ggujadhur\Downloads\.", vbExclamation, "Document doesn't exist."
    MsgBox "File " & DocName & vbCrLf & "not found " & vbCrLf & "C:\Users\nicolas.jouffroy\Downloads\.", vbExclamation, "Document doesn't exist."
    Exit Sub
End If

DocApp.Activate

Set DocFile = DocApp.Documents(DocName)

If DocFile Is Nothing Then Set DocFile = DocApp.Documents.Open(DocName)

DocFile.Activate

'Dim wordrange As Word.Range
'Set rng = wdDoc.Content

'word file part


For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell In row.Cells   
    cell.Copy
    DocFile.Content.InsertAfter cell.Value
    DocFile.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = wdStyleHeading1
    DocFile.Content.InsertAfter vbCr
    
  Next cell
Next row

'word file save etc.
DocFile.Save
'DocApp.Quit

Set DocFile = Nothing
Set DocApp = Nothing
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'word file save etc.


End Sub

The script works for the excel file parsing and pasting into the word file, but it does not format the pasted text to Heading1.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Nicolas
PS: I tried re-writing the code to test formatting to Bold the last paragraph, and that works. I also tried to program a selection, then change the style to Heading 1.

You're re-inventing the wheel. Word has a feature called Mail Merge that does that kind of stuff automatically with a few clicks, without writing any code.

True, I had heard of Mail Merge but not really understood what it does until today. Thanks for that. However, there is a limitation that I am not finding how to overcome: the first column is for headings and needs to be skipped if it is repeating, so I don't think this will work for my purpose.

The first column of what? Your data needs to be in an Excel sheet, one record per row, first row with column names to identify the column. Then you can do anything in Word. Tables, repeating sections, whatever.

Your code is failing because you are using Late Binding. This is an unwise choice as there are no advantages to doing that, but plenty of disadvantages, such as the one here.
wdStyleHeading1 is a Word constant. Excel has no concept of what it means.
Now, you could simply supply the value of that constant in your code, or you could make the wise choice and add a reference to Word (Tools | References) and declare your variables correctly as Word objects.
EDIT:
Word object variables should be delared as:
Dim DocApp As Word.Application
Dim DocFile As Word.Document


hi Timothy, I am really a newbie with VBA. Could you please be clearer with your advice: what is the value of wdStyleHeading1 that I should declare to Excel or how do I find it? I have already added the reference to Word. Thanks for your help.

@Nicolas - If you have added the reference to Word you do not need to declare wdStyleHeading1. To find the value of constants use the Object Browser. For the other variables see edit above.
